# Hide group of rows in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide certain group of rows where 1st row after blank row is "xyz" untill next blank row occours. eg

```
**heloo**
a
b

**xyz**
as
df

**hello**
g
j

**xyz**
ghj
gh
jk
jk
```

I want output to be as

```
**heloo**
a
b

**hello**
g
```

Comment: Don't quite get it. Where are the blank rows in your example?

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have edited your question a bit, so the inputs are slighty different.  However, this is the idea of what you need.  Basically, define a range.  Iterate through it until you find xyz.  Set a flag to start hiding every row in the iteration until you find a blank row.

```
Sub HideRows()
    Set r = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    hiderow = False
    For Each c In r.Cells
        If Left(c.Value, 3) = "xyz" Then
            hiderow = True
        ElseIf Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            hiderow = False
        End If
        If hiderow Then
            c.Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to reset `hiderow` in your loop

Comment: maybe I am missing something; but hiderow resets once a blank row is found.

Comment: If you don't find a blank row in subsequent lopps, `hiderow` will still be true, hence hiding irrelevant rows as well

Comment: thankyou thankyou thankyou.... :) :) this is what i wanted... Thanks a lot for great help.